# Scraping multiple URLs in R using sapply

Tags: r

Good afternoon,

Thanks for helping me out with this question.

I have a list of multiple URLs that I am interested in scraping for a specific field.

At the moment, I'm using the function below to return the value I'm interested in for a specific field:

```
dayViews <- function (url) {
  raw <- readLines(url)
  dat  <- fromJSON(raw)
  daily <- dat$daily_views$`2014-08-14` 
  return(daily)
}
```

How do I modify this to run on a list of multiple URLs? I tried using sapply/lapply over a list of URLs, but it gives me the following message:

```
"Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument"
```

If anyone has any suggestions, I would be greatly appreciative.

Many thanks,

Comment: Please include your code for the sapply.  And are you sure the entire vector of urls scrapes without error?  When scraping, you should use `try` liberally.

Answer (score 0):

Doing something similar to you, @yarbaur, I read into R an Excel spreadsheet that keeps all the URLs of a set I want to scrape.  It has columns for company, URL, and XPath.  Then try something like this code where I have substituted for your variable names I made up.  I am not using JSON sites, however:

```
temp <- apply(yourspreadsheetReadintoR, 1,  
              function(x) {
                yourCompanyName <- x[1]
                yourURLS <- x[2]
                yourxpath <- x[3] # I also store the XPath expressions for each site

                fetch <- content(GET(yourURLS))
                locs <- sapply(getNodeSet(fetch, yourxpath), xmlValue)

                data.frame(coName=rep(yourCompanyName, length(locs)), location=locs)
              })
```